# ASP.NET MVC plugins with WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

I would like to ask for solution on this scenario:

1. I have ASP.NET MVC 3 app
2. I need to have pluging availability to this app (client request is going to server and according to url router to proper plugin which returns the View as a result), routing helps me to decide which plugin is for use by operation name. Each plugin has own database for operations.
3. I need wcf service which will be upon the asp.net app and will be consuming the request for data (View) mined from concrete plugin

Any idea how to handle it?

Comment: What you described looks like the plain ASP.NET MVC functionality. What do you call plugins actually? Why do you need WCF? Check out MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) for example: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/760563/55209), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3033697/5520)

Comment: I need wcf for call of BL which is inside of plugin. When client calls method via wcf, I would like to redirect (switch) to concrete plugin which has implemented BL and return the result (for this case plugin api in controler). But how to achieve extensibility? I would like to avoid any additional implementation when new pluging is going to be integrated to application and also contains methods for wcf ... lack of idea